# How can i switch main activity not in manifest?

Tags: android, kotlin

I making android app. I have 3 activites:

first(main) activity which is empty and it's like navigation which ask you to add item.

Second activity which is needed for adding item's details and this activity have accept button which leads you to third activity.

Third activity have all data about item and from now on i want my app to make this activity main (default) activity with saving information about it in device memory.

I decided to make it without database because it should be really simple.

Can you help me with making 3rd acitivity main? Maybe there are some tricks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not clear what you trying to ask. Like if user reached the 3rd activity, in the future if user open the app the app will automatically navigate them to the 3rd activity?

If that's the case, you could save this information in the shared preference, when the app start, the first activity check this value and navigate to the 3rd activity.

Recommend you use a single activity, use fragments for different pages, and use Navigation component to connect them. https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started

Comment: Yeah exactly. I want my app to open in 3rd activity if user reached it. From 3rd activity you can "delete item" and it will open first activity again. I will draw screenshots rn in paint :D. I tried SharedPreferences one time for variables but how can i save this for activity?

Comment: so i've read a little about Framgents. I think it's good solution for me, thank you. But i think Navigation component will not fit for me because my app have like som kind of flow where user starting with nothing, adding a new one and working with it. Navigation will give him too much freedom :)

Comment: When you open the app, and display the  third activity, where would the data of name and color come from? If you want these data persist when user killed the app, and show again next time they open, these data has to go into your disk (sharedpreference or local files/ database)

Comment: " I tried SharedPreferences one time for variables but how can i save this for activity?" So you do unerstand sharedpreference, you cannot save an entire activity into the sharedpreference of course, but you can save the  name and color into shared preference. In your first activity, check if these data exist in sharedpreference, if so navigate to third activity.

Comment: Trying to make two fragments. It's ok but i don't understand how can i work with objects in Fragment. Like i want to initialize my TextView by "findViewById" but it doesn't work :/ (I'm trying to do this in onCreate of Fragment)

Comment: your findViewById don't work in fragment is likely because you are not calling findViewById in the view return from onViewCreated()

Comment: have you got some sources where i can find information how to work with it? It will be great

Comment: i thinking right now about to use only one fragment as invite to add new item, so when i add it i will just hide this fragment and place all my stuff in activity ;) but i think it will be bad code

Comment: i decided to make it that way i explained earlier. One fragment as invite, when i add item this fragment destroys and visibility of this is gone. It's bad i know it but i drowned so deep with this fragments so my project turned into a mess. Better do it how i can, then i save repository as a rollback and then i will try to make 3 fragments in one activity and provide data transition between them :)